# Отличие результата проверки на пустоту массива в разных версиях php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть ряд значений для проверки на пустоту массива:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(" ");
var_dump(empty($arr1));
$arr2 = array(0);
var_dump(empty($arr2));
$arr3 = array(null);
var_dump(empty($arr3));
$arr4 = array(false);
var_dump(empty($arr4));

?>
```

В версии php 5.3.3 у меня выводит все **false**. Но в версиях php 5.4 и выше это будут **true**?

Comment: Вот здесь вы сами можете проверить на 5.3-7.0 http://phptester.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, поведение языковой конструкции `empty` уже давно не менялось, наверное даже в php4 результат был таким же. Результатом в PHP5.x и актуальных 7.0 и 7.1 будет всё так же 4 `false`.

Про будущие версии не скажу. Может когда-нибудь и изменят поведение, но о таких планах пока не было слышно.

Answer (score 0):

У меня версия 5.4 такой результат `bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)`