# Несовпадение выполнения кода с документацией

Tags: php, массивы

Выполняю код на PHP 5.3.3.

```
<?php

$arr1 = array();
var_dump(empty($arr1));

$arr2;
var_dump(empty($arr2));

$arr3 = array(0);
var_dump(empty($arr3));

$arr4 = array(null);
var_dump(empty($arr4));

$arr5 = array(false);
var_dump(empty($arr5));

$arr6 = array("");
var_dump(empty($arr6));

$arr7 = array(" ");
var_dump(empty($arr6));

?>
```

Результат выполнения

```
bool(true) bool(true) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)
```

Он не совпадает с документацией, где указано, что возвращает FALSE, если var существует, и содержит непустое и ненулевое значение. В противном случае возвращает TRUE.  следующие значения воспринимаются как пустые:

```
"" (пустая строка)
0 (целое число)
0.0 (дробное число)
"0" (строка)
NULL
FALSE
array() (пустой массив)
```

Чем это можно объяснить. Результат разный в PHP 3 по сравнению с PHP 4 или 5 ?

Comment: В PHP7 получил точно такой-же результат. bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)

Comment: хорошо, но ведь этот результат не сходится с тем, что написано в документации(указал выше) или я не допонял?

Comment: Это дубль http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599518/186083 ?

Comment: нет..тут вопрос в несоответствии с документацией или я не допонял сути

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для массива `empty` скажет `true` только в том случае, если массив пуст. Т.е. если массив не содержит ни одного элемента.

Ваш массив `$arr1` именно пустой, не содержит ни одного элемента.

`$arr2` вообще не существует.

Все последующие примеры содержат не пустой массив, есть по одному элементу в каждом. Какой именно это элемент - `empty` совершенно не волнует. Массив содержит хотя бы один элемент, значит не пуст, значит `false`.

Об этом явным образом в документации и сказано: `array() (пустой массив)`. Именно пустой массив рассматривается как `empty`

Comment: но в документации пишется, что следующие значения воспринимаются как пустые: null, false,  0, "0". Что это имелось ими ввиду? Ведь они ж не пустые и вернут empty false.

Comment: @Sven и при чем тут массивы? Вы не путайте пустоту переменной массива, и пустоту его элементов.

Comment: `$var = null; var_dump(empty($var));` будет true. null - рассматривается как пустое значение. `array( null )` - является массивом. В массиве есть один элемент. Значит это не пустой массив и empty скажет false. В сами данные в массиве empty не полезет, это не его забота.

Comment: спасибо за это сообщение..понял теперь!